# Is "product I want to have made" and "product I want to be made" grammatical?

Tags: grammar

I was trying to write something, but then it occurred to me it doesn't sound quite right.

> Here is the blueprint of **the product I want to have made**. Can you make
>   it for me?

It doesn't sound quite idiomatic, so I was wondering if it was correct. Also, is the alternate version any better or equally wrong?

> Here is the blueprint of **the product I want to be made**. Can you make
>   it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Want to be made`, in the passive voice, would be heard as "wishful thinking". If you have an actual product you are paying someone to make, the first example is correct, idiomatic English.